# How many arguments does the product $v\otimes f$ have?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Let $V$ be a vector space. I've learnt that the tensor $v\otimes f$, where $v\in V$ and $f\in V^*$, is given by

$
v\otimes f: V^*\times V\to\mathbb{R}\\
\quad\quad\quad\quad\, (g,\omega)\mapsto v(g)f(\omega).
$

Now I'm trying to understand the isomorphism between $V\otimes V^*$ and $End(V)$. People say that

$
v\otimes f: \omega\mapsto f(\omega)v.
$

So this is taking only one entry (the vector $\omega$), but why? Shouldn't it take a linear functional besides the vector?

Comment: It is meant to define a map from $V$ to itself, so it should indeed only take one vector as input.

Comment: I understand that, but how do we reconcile this with my first definition which takes two entries?

Comment: The first definition is not defining the element $v\otimes f$, it is defining a bilinear form on $V^*\times V$.

Comment: I don't get it. It seems to me that there's two different definitions of the same object. Could you expand more on this? Maybe as an answer?

Comment: I am not sure which object you mean. There is not a definition of $v\otimes f$ anywhere here.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I mean the tensor product $v\otimes f$. I thought my first equation was a *definition* of the tensor product. In any case, my real problem is: why in the first equation we have two entries and in the second equation only one?

Comment: Because they are defining two completely different things.

Comment: You're saying that $v\otimes f(\omega)$ has nothing to do with $v\otimes f(g,\omega)$? So why do we use the same "$v\otimes f$" then?

Comment: Neither of those things define anything like that. One thing defines a map from $V^*\times V\to \mathbb{R}$ and the other defines a map from $V\otimes V^*\to End(V)$. Why would they be related?

Answer (score 1):

You are implicitly using the canonical map $V \to V^{\ast\ast}$ given by $v\mapsto \text{ev}_v$, where $\text{ev}_v$ is the evaluation linear functional on $V^{\ast}$ sending $\phi$ to $\phi(v)$. This is an isomorphism in the finite dimensional case, which you probably also are assuming. This makes $v\in V$ into a map $v:V^\ast\to\Bbb R$ by $v(\psi) = \psi(v)$, and likewise $\phi\in V^\ast$ is a map $\phi:V\to\Bbb R$.

The tensor product $V\otimes V^\ast$ is isomorphic to the vector space of bilinear maps $V^\ast\times V\to\Bbb R$, and the isomorphism is given by the map you describe.

If you don't know a definition of a tensor product yet, you can turn this around, and take this as a definition, which in physics is often done.

Whatever definition of $V\otimes V^\ast$ you have, in the finite dimensional case it is canonically isomorphic to $\text{End}V$, and in your description the isomorphism is given by the map you describe: you take a pure tensor (a general element is a sum of these) $v\otimes f$ and say what endomorphism of $V$ it corresponds to.

A less confusing notation would be to include the isomorphism explicitly in the notation: $\Phi:V\otimes V^\ast\to\text{End}V$ is defined by

$$\Phi(v\otimes f)(\omega) = f(\omega)v$$

This shows you how it is defined on elements of the form $v\otimes f$, not general elements of $V\otimes V^\ast$, or equivalently bilinear $\Bbb R$-valued maps on $V^\ast\times V$, but the map is fully determined by linearity. If you prefer you could say, for $F\in V\otimes V^\ast = \text{Bil}(V^\ast\times V, \Bbb R)$

$$\Phi(F)(\omega) = F(-,\omega)$$

This partially evaluated bilinear map is a functional on $V^\ast$, hence is canonically identified with an element of $V$.

If you insist on concreteness, you can fix a basis and regard elements of $V$ as column vectors, those of $V^\ast$ as row vectors, and the tensor product as the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).